# Javascript - Select First Input (With ID)

Tags: javascript, text, input

I am writing a script with pure JS and need to select a text input from a page that has a random name each time:

```
<input type="text" name="N8PkpWeLsNRQBjvwcwKULB57utJx5L2u0Ko" class="form-control" value="">
```

Normally i would select it using ID like:

```
var textinput = document.getElementById("myInput1");
```

There is no ID however, how can i select this element?

As far as i can see it appears to be the only text input on the page.

I planned on setting some text like this:

```
HTMLInputElement.prototype.setText = function(text) {
    this.value = text;
};

var el = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')[0];
el.setText("Hi");
```

But this does not work for some reason?

Comment: `document.querySelector('input.form-control[type=text]')` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Thanks but when i try: var textinput = document.querySelector('input.form-control[type=text]');textinput.setText("Hi"); it doesn't seem to set the text?

Comment: See the working snippet in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelector(selectors)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) it returns the first matching element within the document.

```
document.querySelector('input.form-control[type=text]')
```

```js
HTMLInputElement.prototype.setText = function(text) {
  this.value = text;
};
var textinput = document.querySelector('input.form-control[type=text]');
textinput.setText("Hi, You can no use setText method.");
```

```html
<input type="text" name="N8PkpWeLsNRQBjvwcwKULB57utJx5L2u0Ko" class="form-control" value="">
```

Comment: This looks like it should work but it does not work on the actual page i run the code on for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

To get the first text field use the following.

```
var txtField=document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')[0];
```

To set the text you could simply do.

```
txtField.value="your Value";
```

Comment: How would i set the inputs text? See my edited post.

Comment: This does not work on the actual page either, i am running a tampermonkey script and an alert pops up fine but neither this or the answer above sets the text for some reason. I would post the URL if it is ok but i notice stackoverflow always removes them.

Answer (score 1):

This way you can select any HTML tag , since you only have 1 input, this should work for you

```
   var input = document.getElementByName('input');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var x = document.getElementsbyClassname("form-control").getAttribute("value");
```